# Remover extensión de archivo en la URL de una pagina web

Tags: html, .htaccess

Tengo un archivo .htaccess en la carpeta de mi host donde esta index.html con el siguiente código:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html`

En teoría con eso y removiendo la extensión en el html debería de mostrar la url así: dirección/ejemplo y no así dirección/ejemplo.html. Quizás sea algo de la configuración del server. En Server Api de `phpinfo()` dice CGI/FastCGI

Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Si no es apache... que servidor es? NGINX?

Comment: Es un hosting web pero no encuentro el apache en phpinfo

Comment: Actualice la publicación.

Comment: Me podrías decir lo que pone en `$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` desde el phpinfo()? Supongo que tienes un servidor NGINX. (Por eso no funciona el `.htaccess`) Tienes acceso por `ssh` a tu servidor?

Comment: En $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] dice Microsoft-IIS / 10.0

Answer (score 0):

tu fallo creo que esta en la /.html, prueba con esto:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```